# Tkinter button function doesn't work properly

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a function that gets called from a button. It has a time.sleep()

```
def func():
    button.place_forget()
    text = Label(root, text = "Text"
    text.place(x = 0, y = 0, in_ = root)
    time.sleep(1)
    text.place_forget()

button = Button(root, text = "Button", command = func)
```

When this gets called, I expect the button to first disappear then the text to appear then wait for 1 second then for the text to disappear. But what happens is the program waits for 1 second then adds the text immediately removes it and then makes the button disappear. How do I get it to work the way I want?

Comment: Could you trying chaging your `command` to `command=lambda:func()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `after()` instead of `sleep()`:

```py
def func():
    button.place_forget()
    text = Label(root, text="Text")
    text.place(x=0, y=0)
    # schedule to remove the text after 1 second
    text.after(1000, text.place_forget)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
button = Button(root, text = "Button", command = func())
button.pack()
```

Comment: `command=func()` will execute `func()` immediately, not at button clicked.